# Unicode String conversion

Tags: android, string, unicode, textview

I've a strange problem with unicode characters in android: if I `setText("\u00e8")` it displays '`è`' and It's right, but if I do something like this, It doesn't:

```
   System.out.println(bob); // "\u00e81"
   String mess=bob.substring(1,bob.length()-2); // \u00e8
   textView.setText(mess); // this prints \u00e8
```

why???? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you device won't support that letters (means Font)

Comment: bob.length() in your case is 1. And you trying get substring from 1 character to -1 == (1-2) character. This is must return null.

Comment: @blackbelt he print 'bob'. Then he setText( null), because mess == null, because bob.substring(1,bob.lenhth()-2) == bob.substring(1,-1) == null

Comment: Use 'mess=bob.substring(0,bob.length()-1);' as my answer below

Comment: I'm sorry but the string bob has the doublequotes , it's not simply "\u00e81" but it's " "\u00e81" ", the substring is to remove the double quotes and '1' to make \u00e8 that is 'è'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
 String bob = "\u00e81";
 System.out.println( bob);
 String mess=bob.substring( 0, bob.length()-1);
 System.out.println( mess);
 textView.setText( mess);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the string bob has the doublequotes , it's not simply "\u00e81" but it's " "\u00e81" ", the substring is to remove the double quotes and '1' to make \u00e8 that is 'è'.